# Cumsum in pandas.groupby is slow

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum, large-data

I would like know if there is a faster way to run a cumsum in pandas.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 10000000

values = np.random.randint(1, 100000, n)
ids = values.astype("S10")

df = pd.DataFrame({"ids": ids, "val": values})
```

Now, I want to groupby using ids and get some stats. 
The max for example is pretty fast:

```
 time df.groupby("ids").val.max()
```

CPU times: user 5.08 s, sys: 131 ms, total: 5.21 s
Wall time: 5.22 s

However, the cumsum is very slow:

```
time df.groupby("ids").val.cumsum()
```

CPU times: user 26.8 s, sys: 707 ms, total: 27.5 s
Wall time: 27.6 s

My problem is that I need the cumsum grouped by a key in a large dataset, almost as shown here, but it takes minutes. Is there a way to make it faster?

Thanks!

Comment: cumsum is not implemented in cython ATM, see the issue here:https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4095, so it has to go back-forth python-cython and is slow as a result. pull-requests to update are welcome!

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for your update. Good to know that I am not doing something idiot here at least. =)